# Rails Minitest to handle file creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

An application generates `.png` files that get written to the application's public directory.

```
IO.binwrite("public/ddx/#{@item.id}/c_#{@item.section_id}_#{@item.aisle_id}.png", png.to_s)
```

However testing the method leads to the test failing to handle a `public` directory

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - public/ddx/1622972374/c_2_31.png
```

the `1622972374` represents `item.id`

How can minitest be coerced to handling this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask how to code minitest, change your code first, make the image path work on both side

```rb
image_path = Rails.root.join('public', 'ddx', ...)
IO.binwrite(image_path, ...)
```